# PIC microcontroller restarts command

Tags: microcontroller, pic, circuit-design, pic16f

I set my pic microcontroller (16f688) to energize a relay after 3 secs and to energize two more relays another 2 secs after. Problem is, sometimes, after it executes this command, it deenergizes the relays and repeats the command again, and again. Sometimes as much as 7 times before it finally settles. Sometimes, it starts again after the first relay is energized.  Sometimes it works fine. It's kinda random, what could be the problem?

Please note that I used an analog pin to monitor input AC mains voltage. The monitoring circuit steps down mains to small DC voltage

Comment: Please provide a schematic and a picture of your setup to give us something to go on...

Comment: Do the relay contacts turn a load on/off? What is the load? Does the PIC boot even if no load is connected?

Comment: EMI most likely. Unless your layout and bypassing is horrible, probably noise from the relay contacts (disconnecting the loads would distinguish between the two). Need much more information to comment sensibly.

Comment: What about the watchdog? Since you don't mention it, assume it is a problem. Having it disabled is a problem. Enabling it but using it incorrectly is a problem.

Comment: Let's first check the basics : What decoupling caps did you use ? Are the cap close to the power pins ?
Do you have a freewheeling diode across the relays ?
Floating PGM pin with low voltage programming mode enabled ?
Please provide the schematics.

Comment: I used electrolytic capacitors for decoupling

Comment: @spehro. With or without load it still acts the same

Comment: please provide schematics.

Comment: And source code!

Answer (score 1):

This may be an electromagnetic compatibility (EMC) problem.

I used to perform a test that always works: put a relay close to a microcontroller and deenergize it and you will see how the microcontroller will either stall (starts executing an unexpected code in the memory) or restart. This test was a good way to test the Watchdog timer reset.

try to put a LED with a resistor in place of each relay. If the problem is solved then it is an EMC problem and in this case separate physically the relays or use enhanced drivers to avoid this problem. If the problem persists reconsider reviewing your program.

The EMC could also come from the power supply. Separate the Power supplying the relays from the power supplying the microcontroller. Use filters (capacitors) in the right places.

The problem can also be a weak power supply that drops when current is high. or dynamically inefficient in regulation.

Comment: The relays are close to each other and quite close to the MCU. But I think the watchdog timer is off. I used MikroC

Comment: If the watchdog timer is off than the problem does not come from it. (If active, the watchdog timer restarts the mcu if the firmware does not reset it before a timeout)